# Joomla category blog is displaying only a number of leading articles in the 'blog' section, and putting all other leading articles outside of it

Tags: overrides, template-override, category-blog, mod-articles-category

Okay so this has gotten me stuck for more than i'd like to admit. I made a joomla ovverride for blogs just to test it out. I see the code below:

```
<?php if (!empty($this->lead_items)) : ?>
    <div class="items-leading clearfix test">
        <?php foreach ($this->lead_items as &$item) : ?>
            <div class="leading-<?php echo $leadingcount; ?><?php echo $item->state == 0 ? ' system-unpublished' : null; ?>"
                itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                <?php
                $this->item = & $item;
                echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
                ?>
            <?php $leadingcount++; ?>
      </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</div><!-- end items-leading -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

For some odd reason, the code looks like this:
[image]

Notice how after leading-6 the remaining articles are displaying OUTSIDE of the 'blog' and 'items-leading' divs. Now I thought I was going crazy cause looking at the over ride it doesn't seem like it should do that. Basically I'm trying to understand why the code looks like every leading article SHOULD be inside the 'items-leading' class but most of them are not (notice how < end items-leading -> appears on the code and on the output HTML, and notice where the 'items-leading' div is on the joomla over ride).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this was just a weird issue. Turns out I disabled article number 6 and everything went to normal, I copied the article onto my local machine and checked all the divs to make sure they matched, everything was fine. Pasted it back in and republished the article, and now the entire category blog is working :/

So heads up for anyone one that runs into the same issue, just check to see if there's a missing div tag where the category blog is breaking.